# перехватить iframe клик

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

Имеется простенькая верстка, которую даже приводить смысла нет, див, в который при помощи `innerHTML` дописывается `iframe` - в этом элементе лежит ютуб-видео(берется из АПИ).

Мне необходимо при нажатии на данное видео перехватывать клик, и переносить пользователя на непосредственно само видео на ютубе.

Вопрос: каким образом в `iframe` можно перехватить play ютуб-видео, и вместо проигрывания на моем сайте, редиректнуть его на новую вкладку непосредственно на ютуб?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9185625/hook-to-click-event-inside-embedded-youtube-player

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Думаю что тут все так просто и объяснять не надо ничего 
Просто ссылка прозрачная поверх iframe

```css
.block {
  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 5px;
}

a {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 100;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class='block'>
  <a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=txByrfFXFv0&t=2s" target="_blank"></a>
  <iframe width="300" height="200" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/txByrfFXFv0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
```

Comment: Не совсем то. Я думаю, он имел ввиду, что при нажатии кнопки play на видео, оно должно новую вкладку открыть.

Comment: @ШерзодЁров,  может быть ты и прав...

Comment: Ну тогда тут iframe не поможет...  это совсем по другому надо исполгять

Comment: @Air я думал про ссылку поверх фрейма, но неужели нет способов сделать это с перехватом события в самом фрейме или вроде того?Дело в том, что мне необходимо иметь само видео с превью на своей странице, а по нажатию переводить на непосредственно ютуб.

Comment: Есть, но это уже не iframe...  а надо полностью реализовывать через API youtube...  Но скажу честно, я могу ошибаться... Хотя на процентов 99%% я уверен, что прав, по этому и пишу...

Comment: посмотри ссылку  https://ruseller.com/lessons.php?id=2425&rub=37

Comment: Просто дело в том, что через  iframe, ты получаешь страницу..  а что бы управлять все этим богатством возможностей, реализация другая...

Comment: можешь реализовать так, ссылку непосредственно на тот элемент наложить, по которому хочешь реализовать переход...

Comment: @Air разве это не для реализации плеера на своей странице?

Comment: Да, так и есть... А ты как хочешь перебрасывать посетителя на сайт youtube...?  В какой момент и как хотел бы это реализовать? Опиши ситуацию  нормально...  В вопросе нет конкретики...